# What is a phase space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, definition, phase-space, chaos-theory, complex-systems

What is a [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space)? And can the phase space be specified with x and y instead of with theta and omega?
I am currently working on a problem where I am graphing the trajectories of three masses (the three-body problem). Is the plot of their superimposed trajectories (x vs. y in space, no z as the angular momentum is zero) considered a phase space?

Comment: What do you mean by $\theta$ and $\omega$? Also, what did you not understand on the Wikipedia article?

Comment: Btw, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) to type equations and mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 1):

In phase space the state of the entire system is represented by one point. If you are plotting trajectories there is a separate point for each object. So this cannot be a phase space.

You may have been confused by the simplest example of a phase space which is that of a simple pendulum. Even though the pendulum is moving in a two-dimensional plane, its motion is constrained by its constant length, so the position of the pendulum can be represented just one value - its angle $\theta$. To capture the state of the pendulum we need two values - $\theta$ and its first derivative $\dot \theta$. Once we know these two values at any given time, then we can find the state of the pendulum at any other time. So the pendulum's phase space has just two dimensions. But phase spaces generally have many more than two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The phase space for 3 masses ($1, 2, 3$) is formed by the combination of all their positions and momenta:

$$(x_1, y_1, z_1,x_2, y_2, z_2,x_3, y_3, z_3,
p_{x_1}, p_{y_1}, p_{z_1},p_{x_2}, p_{y_2}, p_{z_2},p_{x_3}, p_{y_3}, p_{z_3})$$

so it's 18 dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

The wiki article encapsulates it:

> [In dynamical system theory,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) a phase space is a space in which all possible states of a system are represented, with each possible state corresponding to one unique point in the phase space. For mechanical systems, the phase space usually consists of all possible values of position and momentum variables. It is the outer product of direct space and reciprocal space.

[This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/phase.html) is useful for physics:

> Statistics involves the counting of states, and the state of a classical particle is completely specified by the measurement of its position and momentum. If we know the six quantities

$x,y,z,p_x,p_y,p_z$

> then we know its state. It is often convenient in statistics to imagine a six-dimensional space composed of the six position and momentum coordinates. It is conventionally called "phase space". The counting tasks can then be visualized in a geometrical framework where each point in phase space corresponds to a particular position and momentum. That is, each point in phase space represents a unique state of the particle. The state of a system of particles corresponds to a certain distribution of points in phase space.

Note " each point in phase space represents a unique state of the particle".
The concept  can be generalized to any coordinate type  description , as long it uniquely defines the coordinates of the particle.